# Proper disposal of Images in EMGU

Tags: c#, memory-management, emgucv

Im using EMGU (opencv wrapper) for image processing. I want to load images one by one from a folder to perform some operations on them. I use the following code and would do some operations in the using block.

```
        string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(directory);


        foreach(string filename in filenames)
        {

            using (Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(filename))
            {



            }

        }
```

However, when I run the code the application uses a growing chunk of memory till I get some exception regarding addressing or being out of memory.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code looks fine. My guess would be one or more of the operations you are performing for each image is allocating a copy of the image that's not being cleaned up.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. Had to ensure that I properly disposed of any copies that were made inadvertently. Shouldn't the garbage collector take care of this?

Comment: The GC will take care of managed objects, but EmguCV is just a wrapper around an unmanaged API - that's the memory that's leaking.